# How can I hide element loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, hide

I would like to hide some part of content loaded via ajax, when the content is inserted into html page. those live, bind, and delegate are only for events, what can I use here?? thanks for help.

**update:** initially, the same part was already hidden when the page loaded.

initially, I have something like this:

```
<a id="link" href="">a link</a>
   <ul class="list">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
   </ul>
```

and jquery:

```
$('.list').hide();
$('#link').moserover(function(){
      $('.list').show();
})
```

Now, this part will be replaced with other content received from ajax,which is the same,

```
 <a id="link" href="">another link</a>
   <ul class="list">
         <li>****</li>
         <li>****</li>
   </ul>
```

but when this content is inserted to the page,,, the list is not hidden, my question is how can I hide this list whenever it comes from ajax. hope this is clear.

Comment: Code, code, and some more code, please! This is not a theoretical Q&A. Give us some code to chew on.

Comment: Are you completely injecting the "replaced" code, or are you receiving code and replacing the content between the `<li>` and `<a>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try to have the AJAX return a string of html code to insert. Make sure there is an ID or class for each item that you want to hide. Then through a few simple `.apppend()` or `.html()` calls you can add all that code to your page.

From there its as easy as using `$('#YourID').css('display', 'none');`

Answer (score 4):

if you using [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) then you can perform things in call back function

small example here

```
$('#result').load('server.php', function() {

$(".list").hide();  

});
```

Edit

If you don't want to write code again and again thats good.

So you can declare function and call it where every you want !
like

```
function foo(){

// your code
}

//call it on document load
foo();

 $('#result').load('server.php', function() {    
    foo();    
    });
```

but in your case it just single line code.if you still like to simplify it, Thats simple

```
var myele =  $(".list");

myele.hide();
myele.show();
```

Hope it helps it

Comment: but initially, I have that 'hide' code, I don't want to write it agian. could that be hidden without writing that again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it hidden by default when it first loads, use CSS in a stylesheet or put an inline style on it in the markup.  That will make it's default condition hidden.  If, there's some reason you can't do that, then right after it is loaded via ajax, you can hide it with jQuery.

If there's more to your question than this, please clarify or explain in more detail what you want.

Suppose the content you're adding is this:

```
<div id="myAjaxContent">My content here</div>
```

Then, you could just have CSS in your stylesheet like this and the element will automatically be hidden without you having to do anything else (no jQuery required):

```
#myAjaxContent {display: none;}
```

or you could have an inline style on the content:

```
<div id="myAjaxContent" style="display: none;">My content here</div>
```

Or, if you want to show/hide it with code, you can use this right after the ajax call completes (it is your code that loads it via ajax so you can run any code you want after it's loaded):

```
$("#myAjaxContent").hide();
```

`.live()` is only for events like clicks.  You can't use `.live()` to automatically call `hide()` on any new elements.  You would use pre-defined CSS (either in a stylesheet or inline on the object) to do that.

If you want it to be easy to toggle visibility later, then put a specific class on the object:

```
<div id="myAjaxContent" class="notVisible" style="display: none;">My content here</div>
```

and have a pre-defined CSS stylesheet rule like this:

```
.notVisible {display: none;}
```

The, later on, if you want to programmatically show the object, you can just do:

```
$("#myAjaxContent").removeClass("notVisible");
```

and that will show it.

Comment: If the element is generated and injected after the ajax call, wouldn't `.live()` need to be used?

Comment: @bingjie2680 yes, you could use `.live()`, but it might not be necessary. Your code still leaves some questions.

Comment: could you please show me how to use live()...in live() API the first param needs an event type...but here there is no event..

Comment: @bingjie2680 - There's no reason to use .live here if you just want it hidden.  I added more of an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Added one more option to my answer - a class that makes it hidden by default that you can later remove if you want to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

display:hidden .. via css ..

```
$(".elementid").css("display","none");
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$(".elementid").css("display","none");`?

Comment: Don't you mean `$("#elementid").css("display","none");`? "." is for selecting by class.

Comment: Can you expand on how/why this works to resolve the question?

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for rethinking your current method.

You are making an AJAX call and returning a whole block of HTML, which is structurally similar to what you already had in the page when you loaded it. This seems a little inefficient, and creates more overhead (as you are seeing).

Try returning the `li` or `a` values in JSON/XML, then using `.text()` to replace the values in the HTML. This will be beneficial in a few ways; you're reducing the size of your response and accomplishing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the solutions:

```
$("#myAjaxContent").fadeOut(1);
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.